# Simple string parsing without using boost

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Splitting a string in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/splitting-a-string-in-c)

I'm working on an assignment for my C++ class and I was hoping I could get some help. One of my biggest problems in coding with C++ is parsing strings. I have found longer more complicated ways to parse strings but I have a very simple program I need to write which only needs to parse a string into 2 sections: a command and a data section. For instance: `Insert 25` which will split it into Insert and 25.

I was planning on using an array of strings to store the data since I know that it will only split the string into 2 sections. However I also need to be able to read in strings that require no parsing such as `Quit`

What is the simplest way to accomplish this without using an outside library such as boost?

Comment: How do you "receive" these strings - file, standard input, socket, etc? Read more about `std::string` and it's member functions.

Comment: I get the data through user input using cin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read strings from a stream using [`getline`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/), and then to a split by finding the firs position of a space character `' '` within the string, and using the [`substr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/) function twice (for the command to the left of the space and for the data to the right of space).

```
while (cin) {
     string line;
     getline(cin, line);
     size_t pos = line.find(' ');
     string cmd, data;
     if (pos != string::npos) {
         cmd = line.substr(0, pos-1);
         data = line.substr(pos+1);
     } else {
         cmd = line;
     }
     cerr << "'" << cmd << "' - '" << data << "'" << endl;
}
```

Here is [a link to a demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/q6AteO).

Answer (score 2):

The *simplest* may be like this:

```
string s;
int i;

cin >> s;
if (s == "Insert")
{
    cin >> i;
    ... // do stuff
}
else if (s == "Quit")
{
    exit(0);
}
else
{
    cout << "No good\n";
}
```

The simplest way may be not so good if you need e.g. good handing of user errors, extensibility etc.

Answer (score 1):

This is another way :

```
string s("Insert 25");
istringstream iss(s);
do
{
   string command; int value;
   iss >> command >> value;
   cout << "Values: " << command << " " << values << endl;
} while (iss);
```

Answer (score 0):

I like using streams for such things.

```
int main()
{
    int Value;
    std::string Identifier;
    std::stringstream ss;
    std::multimap<std::string, int> MyCollection; 

    ss << "Value 25\nValue 23\nValue 19";

    while(ss.good())
    {
            ss >> Identifier;
            ss >> Value;
            MyCollection.insert(std::pair<std::string, int>(Identifier, Value));
    }

    for(std::multimap<std::string, int>::iterator it = MyCollection.begin(); it != MyCollection.end(); it++)
    {
            std::cout << it->first << std::endl;
            std::cout << it->second << std::endl;
    }

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

This way you can allready convert your data into the needed format. And the stream automatically splits on whitespaces. It works the same way with std::fstream if your working with files.